# How do I delete a Gmail filter that is set on a specific word - no other criteria and it does not show under filter with settings

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels

I am learning how to set up filters for the first time and I mistakenly asked for a filter for the word Confirmation in "contains the word" instead of subject.  Now my label for shopping confirmation has thousands of emails - and is grabbing emails from everything from flight info to my son's road test - not online shopping!  I know how to delete a filter based on an email address, but not a specific word.  I have googled but with no success.

Answer (score 2):

The filters are shown in the Gmail settings on the Gmail web app. If the filter is not shown there, something else is adding the label.

To find the filters, click the **Settings** button (gear / cogwheel icon), then **See all settings**. Another option is to go directly to https://mail.google.com/mail/#settings/filters.